# from a laptop with CentOS 6.3 what is the command line to talk mysql server on my pc?

Tags: command-line, mysql, desktop, laptop

I have CentOS 6.3 running on my laptop which is already connected to the net.

What is the command line to talk to MySQL server on my PC?

Both devices are connected via my router and they can talk to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the `ip-address` of the PC where the MYSQL server is running using `ifconfig` command.

Then from your laptop, run the following command.

```
$ mysql --host=ip-address --user=user_name --password=password
```

where,

```
   user_name = a user who have access to db,
   password  = password of the above user.
```